# Why there is no Server Name under integration services in SSMS?

Tags: ssis, ssms, ssms-2017

I cant connect to Integration Services in SSMS there is no Server Name under it when I browse , if I type manually the server name based on how other services have it says class not registered

[image: No Server Name Under Integration Services]

[image: Also there is no server name if I check under browse]

Answer (score 1):

If someone else has the same problem the reason was because I had installed SSIS 2017 but was using SSMS 18.x , if you have SSIS 2017 use SSMS 17.x and such with other versions